# Scroll web page up

Tags: jquery, scroll

I want my webpage to scroll up when a user hovers the cursor over an `<aside>` tag.

I tried this using jquery but was unsuccessful

```
<scrip>
    $( "aside" ).mouseover(function() {
           window.scrollTo(0,500);
        // Animation complete.
    });;
</script>
```

Comment: You also have a typo here. `<scrip>` should be `<script>`.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong in your inner function code, the method you should use is [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) (included in jQuery).

The sentence you should put is:

```
$(window).scrollTo(0);
```

You need to put the jQuery function with the window object as a parameter to scroll it to position 0.

EDIT: I saw that window.scrollTo is valid too, if you want to scroll the page to top, the sentence you are looking for is:

```
window.scrollTo(0,0);
```

The first parameter is the x position, and the second is the y position.